# regular expression check if number is whole number or float i think

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all I need an if and else statement that checks if two fields which are min and max are numbers and these numbers can be whole numbers like 0 or 12 or they could be 0.50 to 1,300.99 does anyone know how to check for numbers my code is in the following format:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#price_range').click(function(e) {
        var price_min = $('#min').val();
        var price_max = $('#max').val();
        var error_msg = "";

        if(price_min.macth(.../) && price_max.match(.../)) {
            error_msg = "Please enter a valid number."
        }else if(price_min > price_max) {
            error_msg = "Min is greater than max."
        }
    }
```

Comment: check my answer to see whether is works for you or not please..

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need regex for number check. You can do a [`parseFloat` and loose compare](http://jsfiddle.net/SAamN/4/) the results with the initial value.

```
function isNumber(number) {
  var i;
  return (!isNaN(i = parseFloat(number)) && number == i);
}
```

Comment: Yes! Why on earth would you use regular expressions for these simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
  "hello.world",
  "33",
  "25.",
  "2.345",
  "h.50",
  ".50",
];


var regex = /^(?:\d+)?(?:\.)?(?:\d+)?$/;

for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
  if (data[i].match(regex)) {
    console.log(data[i] + " is a number!");
  }
  else {
    console.log(data[i] + ": NOT");
  }
}

    --output:--
    hello.world: NOT
    33 is a number!
    25. is a number!
    2.345 is a number!
    h.50: NOT
    .50 is a number!
```